# OneNote UpdatePageContent

Tags: c#

I am trying to update the page content in OneNote through my C# application. Here is the code I have for doing this:

```
private static void SetElementInPage(string pageId)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.Application m_app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.Application();
    string strPageContent = "<one:Page xmlns:one=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2010/onenote\" ID=\"{0}\" >" +
        "<one:Outline>" +
            "<one:Position x=\"36.0\" y=\"86.4000015258789\" z=\"0\" />" +
            "<one:Size width=\"117.001953125\" height=\"40.28314971923828\" />" +
            "<one:OEChildren>" +
                "<one:OE>" +
                    "<one:T><![CDATA[This is a sample data added to test out OneNote API functionality.  Following is a list item.]]></one:T>" +
                "</one:OE>" +
            "</one:OEChildren>" +
            "<one:OEChildren indent=\"2\">" +
                "<one:OE  alignment=\"left\">" +
                    "<one:List>" +
                        "<one:Bullet bullet=\"2\" fontSize=\"11.0\" />" +
                    "</one:List>" +
                    "<one:T><![CDATA[A for Apple]]></one:T>" +
                "</one:OE>" +
                "<one:OE  alignment=\"left\">" +
                    "<one:List>" +
                        "<one:Bullet bullet=\"2\" fontSize=\"11.0\" />" +
                    "</one:List>" +
                    "<one:T><![CDATA[B for Ball]]></one:T>" +
                "</one:OE>" +
                "<one:OE  alignment=\"left\">" +
                    "<one:List>" +
                        "<one:Bullet bullet=\"2\" fontSize=\"11.0\" />" +
                    "</one:List>" +
                    "<one:T><![CDATA[C for Cat]]></one:T>" +
                "</one:OE>" +
           "</one:OEChildren>" +
        "</one:Outline>" +
        "</one:Page>";
    strPageContent = string.Format(strPageContent, pageId);
    m_app.UpdatePageContent(strPageContent);
}
```

On the final line `m_app.UpdatePageContent(strPageContent);` I am getting an error that reads:

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.dll but was not handled in user code
```

The method `setElementInPage(string pageId)` is also called in the code below:

```
private async void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    GetNamespace();
    string notebookId = GetObjectId(null, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsNotebooks, "Aaron @ Microsoft");
    string sectionId = GetObjectId(notebookId, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsSections, "New Section 1");
    string firstPageId = GetObjectId(sectionId, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsPages, "My Page");
    SetElementInPage(firstPageId);

    Console.Read();
}
```

What could be causing this issue? Any help is appreciated, thanks.